# Как из модуля А отправить даные в модуль В в Python

Tags: python

Как из модуля "А" отправить даные в модуль "В" в Python

MAIN - МОДУЛЬ

```
import tkinter
from socket_server import Socket_Server
class MainInterface:

    def __init__(self):

        self.tk = tkinter.Tk()
        self.tk.title('Server')
        self.tk.geometry("400x250")
        self.create_widgets()



    def send(self, host_entry, port_entry):
        Socket_Server.HOST = self.host_entry
        Socket_Server.PORT = self.port_entry
        return Socket_Server.HOST, Socket_Server.PORT



    host_label = tkinter.Label(self.tk, text="HOST NUMBER")
    host_label.grid(column=0, row=0)

    host_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.tk, width=10)
    host_entry.grid(column=1, row=0)

    port_label = tkinter.Label(self.tk, text="PORT NUMBER")
    port_label.grid(column=0, row=1)

    port_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.tk, width=10)
    port_entry.grid(column=1, row=1)

    send_btn = tkinter.Button(self.tk, text='Send', command=send(host_entry, port_entry))
    send_btn.grid(column=0, row=2)

program = MainInterface()
program.tk.mainloop()
```

ВТОРОЙ-МОДУЛЬ

```
import socket

class Socket_Server:
    socket_server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socket_server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)


    socket_server.bind((HOST,PORT))
    socket_server.listen()

    while True:
        print('Before accept()')
        client_socket, addr = socket_server.accept()
        print('Connection from', addr)

        while True:
            print('Before recv()')
            reguest = client_socket.recv(4096)

            if not reguest:
                break
            else:
                response = "Hello World\n".encode()
                client_socket.send(response)
```

Comment: Который у вас А и который B? Какие их имена? В какой папке они находятся, когда нет в одной и той же самой?

Comment: (A - "tkinterGUI_server.py" MAIN Модуль)
(B - "socket_server.py" ВТОРОЙ-МОДУЛЬ)
В одной и той же самой

Comment: Что вообще значит "отправить"? Напишите нормально, что хотите сделать.

Comment: ввести данные в tkinter (HOST, PORT) и передать их в сервер (HOST, PORT)